# How to move cursor to a pane by index in a tmux session?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

I'm in a tmux session. If I press <kbd>ctrl+b q</kbd>, tmux prints a number for each pane.
[image]

How can I move cursor directly to a pane by these numbers? I don't want to do <kbd>ctrl+b o</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl+b up/down/left/right</kbd>.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just press the number you want to move to, while the numbers are on-screen.  You can adjust the display duration in your `~/.tmux.conf` like so (hitting escape will turn off the numbers so you're not stuck waiting for a long display time to disappear):

```
set -g display-panes-time 3000
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't know it's so easy